# mensaje de alerta

Tags: javascript, html

necesito que mi resultado aparezca en una alerta que diga correcto. He intentado muchos códigos y he tenido un resultado, bueno, lo que quiero es que si digo la palabra correcta me dice en un mensaje correcto y tiene un botón que dice a continuación hay que dejo mi código espero tu ayuda...

**Código Javascript:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (typeof speechSynthesis == 'undefined' || typeof webkitSpeechRecognition == 'undefined')
        return alert('Only Chrome browser is supported');

    var $success = new Audio('correct.mp3');
    var $tada = new Audio('tada.mp3');  
    
    var $button = document.querySelector('#page-card #button'); 
    var $image = document.querySelector('#page-card #image');
    var $word = document.querySelector('#page-card #word');
    var $translate = document.querySelector('#page-card #translate');
    var $answer = document.querySelector('#page-card #answer');
    
    $image.addEventListener('click', e => speakText($word.textContent));
                
    var voice;
    loadVoices();
    if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) 
        speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => loadVoices();   
    

    var group, cardNo;
    document.querySelectorAll('#page-selector .group').forEach(function ($e) {
        $e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            group = e.target.id;
            togglePage();
            showCard(0);
        });
    });
    
    document.querySelectorAll('#page-card #option > *[ref]').forEach(function ($e) {

        $e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            this.toggleAttribute('pushed');
            const $div = document.querySelector('#page-card #' + this.getAttribute('ref'));
            console.log(this.getAttribute('ref'), $div);    
            $div.style.visibility = $div.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        });
    });


    function speakText(text) {
        var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
        utterance.voice = voice;
        utterance.rate = 0.8;
        speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    };

    function loadVoices () {
        voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
            .find((e, i) => i > 0 && e.lang.indexOf('en') == 0 && (e.lang.indexOf('US') != -1 || e.lang.indexOf('UK') != -1 || e.lang.indexOf('GB') != -1));
             
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then (function (stream) {
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.interimResults = false;
        recognition.lang = 'en';
        
        function start() {
            recognition.start();
            $button.setAttribute('hold', true);
        }
        
        function stop () {
            recognition.stop();
            $button.removeAttribute('hold');            
        }

        $button.addEventListener('mousedown', start);
        $button.addEventListener('touchstart', start);

        $button.addEventListener('mouseup', stop);
        $button.addEventListener('touchend', stop);
        
        recognition.onresult = function (event) {
            var answer = event.results[0][0].transcript.toLowerCase();
            $answer.innerHTML = answer;
            if (answer == data[group][cardNo].word || data[group][cardNo].alt && data[group][cardNo].alt.indexOf(answer) != -1) {
                if (cardNo < data[group].length - 1) {
                    $success.play();
                    showCard(cardNo + 1);
                } else {
                    $tada.play();
                    togglePage();
                }   
            }
        }
        recognition.onerror = err => $error.innerHTML = err.message;
        
    }).catch((err) => alert(err.message));
    
    
    function showCard(no) {
        cardNo = no;
        var curr = data[group][cardNo];
        $image.style.backgroundImage = `url('images/${group}/${curr.word}.jpg')`;
        $word.innerHTML = curr.word;
        $translate.innerHTML = curr.translate;
        $answer.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
    
    function togglePage() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.page').forEach($e => $e.toggleAttribute('current'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Que error te da? En que función en especifico te da el error?

Comment: No me da ningun error lo que quiero esque cuando yo pronuncie bien un numero etc en ces de un sonido salga un mensaje que diga correcto y con un boton que me diga siguiente para pronuncia la otra palabra

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código se encuentra el problema? ¿Qué has **depurado** y qué resultados obtienes?

Comment: El resultado que obteno es un sonido que esta llamado como tada ahora yo no quiero que salfa el sonido si un aletra que de que lo que estou pronunciando me digo correcto